# How To Upgrade HAProxy On Debian VM?

Tags: linux, debian, haproxy

Does someone have clear instructions for upgrading HAProxy to the latest stable release?

We're presently using 1.8.19 on a Debian VM and need to upgrade it to 2.1.3.

I came across the following instructions: https://blog.geralexgr.com/linux/upgrade-haproxy-to-2-1-3-red-hat-enterprise-linux-server-centos

However, they really aren't clear for someone who's never done this before. I don't want to be compiling source code unless I absolutely have to.

Running apt-get install haproxy says I'm on the latest version. Why then do I see 2.1.3 as the latest stable release?

Any help would be appreciated, as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apt-get install will tell you you're on the latest version that's defined in the Debian repository for haproxy. At release time, Debian fixes versions of software it ships with to provide a stable interface and only minor and security updates will be applied to it. They won't switch to a new major version of Haproxy in the same Debian release, as existing installations might break. In fact, Debian is (in)famous for providing very stable (yet slightly older) versions of the software in it's repository.

In order to get a newer Haproxy version, you would have to look outside the Debian provided repositories (or build it yourself). Fortunately, for HAproxy there are repositories available, which you can find at https://haproxy.debian.net/.

You didn't provide your exact Debian version, but for Buster (10) it would be something like this:

```
# curl https://haproxy.debian.net/bernat.debian.org.gpg \
      | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/haproxy.debian.net.gpg
# echo deb "[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/haproxy.debian.net.gpg]" \
      http://haproxy.debian.net buster-backports-2.1 main \
      > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/haproxy.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get install haproxy=2.1.\*
```

Comment: Thanks, @mtak! That resolved the issue for me, and I was able to upgrade quite easily in the end!